# combining redis databases into single instance

Tags: redis, replication

We have two redis instances that are overprovisioned on AWS (`oldhost1`, `oldhost2`) and I'm wondering if it's possible to combine that data into a single `newhost1`

Is it possible to replicate
oldhost1/db0 -> newhost1/db0
oldhost2/db1 -> newhost1/db1

I tried setting up newhost1 to replcate from oldhost1, which sucked in oldhost1's data - but then when I repointed replication at oldhost2, it clobbered the data already replicated.

Comment: You cannot achieve the goal with replication. Instead, you can use `SCAN` + `MIGRATE` command to migrate data from one instance to another.

Comment: thanks! - `SCAN` + `MIGRATE` presumably require amount of downtime and/or non-"synciness" though, yea?

Comment: You might want to stop writing before the migration is done. But reading will not be affected.